# When navigating to #id, element is hidden under fixed position header

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I have a Bootstrap 3.0 navbar with that is always visible at the top of the page, but this could represent anything for which the `position` property is `fixed`.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" >
```

Because fixing it takes it out of the document flow, I need to add some padding to the body element so the content isn't hidden when the page is first display

```css
body {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

The problem is that when I click a menu item to navigate to a section, like `#About` then the top of the section is cut off.

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/gDLJm/2/)

*Q:* Is there a way to adding padding so that the full item will come into view when navigated to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would set the `overflow: hidden` on the body and add your site's content to a scrollable element.

Your layout should look like this:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar"></div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <!-- rest of content for site -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Add these CSS rules:

```css
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.wrap {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

#### [Check out my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gDLJm/4/)

Comment: This is better, though there are implications for using `height:100%;` as some of the content will be trailing depending on how high the nav bar is.

Comment: That is great!  Much less hackish and actually looks the way I want it to.  Follow up question, if I'm using the margin trick (`.wrap { margin: 0 auto; }`) to center my content, can I avoid the additional scrollbar in the middle of the page with your approach.  See [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/gDLJm/6/)

Comment: Yes, in this case you have to wrap the content within another div and apply overflow:auto to the outer div (the one that is 100% in width). Check my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gDLJm/7/

Comment: the scrollbar is generally a browser's president, but there are certain vendor-specific CSS properties you can use to stop them appearing. It's not advised if you're not providing them with an alternative to scrolling though.

Comment: perhaps I stand corrected...

Answer (score 8):

## Updated Answer:

As described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12606867/1366033), The problem is, your browser always wants to scroll your anchor to the exact top of the window. If you set your anchor where your text actually begins, it will be occluded by your menu bar.

*Instead*, set the `padding-top` for the container to the amount offset you want, and the `margin-top` for the container to the ***opposite*** of the padding-top. Now the container's block and the anchor begin at the exact top of the page, but the content inside doesn't begin until below the menu bar.

```css
section {
    padding-top: 60px;
    margin-top: -60px;
}
```

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/gDLJm/9/)

Comment: but this results in padding between the title and the bounding box of the element. Is that really what you want?

Comment: love you! this solve my problem!