# Bootstrap 3 navigation - Change when active class is added on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have a fixed navbar on my site using pretty much all Bootstrap defaults. I have a bit of jQuery for some one page navigation scrolling:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.page-scroll").bind("click", function(e) {
        var t = $(this);
        $("html, body").stop().animate({
            scrollTop: (parseInt($(t.attr("href")).offset().top)-40)
        }, 1500, "easeInOutExpo");
        e.preventDefault()
    })
});
```

This works ok. I add the `-40` to the offset top to ensure there is enough space between the header of each section and the fixed navbar.

My html looks a bit like this:

```
<section id="pricing" class="pricing-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
```

So the nav adds the active class based on the `#pricing` section offset top. This is fine if I am just scrollling. But when I click on the nav link and use the jQuery to scroll to that point, the `-40` I have added means it stops before the offset triggers the active class to be added.

This is what I mean:

[image]

So how can I adjust when the bootstrap active class is added to match the `-40px` offset?

**SOLUTION:**

So simple. Found the answer here: [How do I set the offset for ScrollSpy in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288482/how-do-i-set-the-offset-for-scrollspy-in-bootstrap). I just needed to adjust the scroll spy data in my body tag like so:

`<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top" data-offset="40">`

Note the `data-offset="40"` fixed the problem straight away.

Comment: Solved. Solution added above.