# How to make an offset distance for href anchor in bootstrap scrollspy and Affix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The div content covered by navmenu when use href anchor. The div begenning also need to show on anchor click. Is there any option to make a distance to the menu when click on anchor ?

[image]

**Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVKBpW**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
.affix {
  width: 100%;
}
#section1 {
  background-color: #1E88E5;
}
#section2 {
  background-color: #673ab7;
}
#section3 {
  background-color: #ff9800;
}
#section41 {
  background-color: #00bcd4;
}
#section42 {
  background-color: #009688;
}
.customdiv {
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-default {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-default.affix {
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar-default.affix + .container-fluid {
  /* padding-top: 70px */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="1">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="1">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="section1" class="container-fluid customdiv">
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="container-fluid customdiv">
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="container-fluid customdiv">
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section41" class="container-fluid customdiv">
    <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section42" class="container-fluid customdiv">
    <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! s</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288482/how-do-i-set-the-offset-for-scrollspy-in-bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
scrollTop: target.offset().top - 125
```

To be frank, that `- 125` was a trial and error. It should be calculated from the `navbar` height.

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 125
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
.affix {
  width: 100%;
}
#section1 {
  background-color: #1E88E5;
}
#section2 {
  background-color: #673ab7;
}
#section3 {
  background-color: #ff9800;
}
#section41 {
  background-color: #00bcd4;
}
#section42 {
  background-color: #009688;
}
.customdiv {
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-default {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-default.affix {
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar-default.affix + .container-fluid {
  /* padding-top: 70px */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="1">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="1">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="section1" class="container-fluid customdiv">
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="container-fluid customdiv">
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="container-fluid customdiv">
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section41" class="container-fluid customdiv">
    <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section42" class="container-fluid customdiv">
    <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! s</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: your solution seems to me good, but there is flickering while scroll if I click on next menu link before compete the animation 

Answer (score 2):

Try `scrollTop: target.offset().top - 50` and set your `margin-top: 50px;` to the `body`. See example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 50
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body, html {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#section1 {
  background-color: #1E88E5;
}
#section2 {
  background-color: #673ab7;
}
#section3 {
  background-color: #ff9800;
}
#section41 {
  background-color: #00bcd4;
}
#section42 {
  background-color: #009688;
}
.customdiv {
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-default.affix {
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>

      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a>

            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>

              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a>

                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="section1" class="container-fluid customdiv">
    <h1>Section 1</h1>

    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="container-fluid customdiv">
    <h1>Section 2</h1>

    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="container-fluid customdiv">
    <h1>Section 3</h1>

    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section41" class="container-fluid customdiv">
    <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>

    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section42" class="container-fluid customdiv">
    <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>

    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! s</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: your solution seems to me good, but there is flickering while scroll if I click on next menu link before compete the animation 

Comment: What do you mean by "flickering"?