# How do I make an offset of 50% of the page for Scrollspy?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to make my Scrollspy switch to the next section when it reaches 50% of the page height.

I looked at [How do I set the offset for ScrollSpy in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288482/how-do-i-set-the-offset-for-scrollspy-in-bootstrap) and I wasn't able to come up with a solution.

So far i only have the normal data-offset

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#mainNavBar" data-offset="200">
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve it?

Comment: @D_Supreme Like I said. I tried the solutions they posted and adjusted them to be 50% of the screen but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to do the trick.

```
var offsetSize = (screen.height/2);

        //Scrollspy offset
        $("body").scrollspy({target: "#navID", offset:offsetSize});
    });
```