# Link to id but navbar in the way

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with links to a article with `id="about"`, but my navbar is fixed-top, so when I click on the link, my navbar is in front of the title of the section.

I solved this problem by using this: `<span id="about" class="anchor"></span>`

```
.main-content article .anchor{ 
    position: absolute;
    top: -106px;
}
```

But for scrollspy I need the href of the link to be the same as the id of the section where I want to "scrollspy" but I can't use the same id twice.

How can I solve this? Is there a way to go to add `-100px` to your href or something like that?

Comment: [Use the offset option](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/#options). Detailed on the scrollspy page. Did you read this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the offset for ScrollSpy in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288482/how-do-i-set-the-offset-for-scrollspy-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a 'false' anchor like this above your about content:

```
<div style="margin-top: -95px; position: absolute;" id="about"></div>
```

This will add a margin to your section above and after some adjustment you can change the px value to suit your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top-100 }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, I found it easy to just place an anchor tag above where you want to jump to and then add scroll-margin-top to my CSS with a value.

```css
#jumpto {
    scroll-margin-top: (insert value here);
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#jumpto">Nav Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<a id="jumpto"></a>
<section>
    <h2>
        This is where I want to jump to but the stupid navbar is in the way!
    </h2>
</section>
```